# Keeping one form on top of the calling form

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.NET (VS2008) and have a form (frmMain) that calls another form (frmCleanUp) but when frmCleanUp shows it can be hidden behind frmMain.

What I'd like to have is the new form be locked and have to close to get rid of it?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Show the `Form` with [`.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of [`.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This way, the form is shown as modal dialog box and will stay on top until you close it.

Comment: with 21.5k reputation I think there's more than luck behind it... :)

Comment: WE HAVE A WINNER!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @GeorgeVaisey Fell free to mark this answer as accepted. It will give both of us some reputation. Also, people may stop answering your questions if they see that you don't regulary mark answers as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

when you show the form, do it with `ShowDialog`

in frmMain do:

```
frmCleanUp.ShowDialog
```